# extract cvs file column in python and redirect to the text file

Tags: python

I have a CVS file, and I want to extract the first column and redirect the output to the text files, but the outputput is not completed shown in a text file. I would appreciate this as I'm a beginner in python. these are my codes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df1 = df[["job_name"]]
f = open("results.txt", "w+")
f.write(str(df1))
```

and the results shown like this in text file, however I want to show and print all 17669 rows.

0      AF-A0A024R1R8-F1

1      AF-A0A024RBG1-F1

2      AF-A0A024RCN7-F1

3      AF-A0A075B6H5-F1

4      AF-A0A075B6H7-F1

...                 ...

17664      AF-S4R3Y5-F1

17665      AF-S4R460-F1

17666      AF-V9GZ13-F1

17667      AF-W6CW81-F1

17668      AF-X6R8D5-F1

[17669 rows x 1 columns]

Answer (score 0):

Just like you used [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to open the file and read it into a dataframe, you can use [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to write a dataframe out to csv - the reverse operation.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df1 = df[["job_name"]]
df1.to_csv("results.txt", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print all rows in a dataframe without the truncation (i.e. ...) you can modify the settings like this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

data = df["job_name"].tolist()
## return a list containing all entry in column

f = open("results.txt", "w+")
f.write("\n".join(data))
## create a string containing all data and separated with new
## line character \n, then write it to your .txt file
```